# Checkbox document.getElementById getting null

Tags: javascript

I want to know whether the checkbox is selected or not. There is a customvalidator  linked to the check box.  Using java script, i am checking the checkbox selected or not

Here is the ASpx  code and  Java script

```js
function checkAcceptance(source, args) {
  args.IsValid = document.getElementById('CheckBox1').checked;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="CheckBox1Resource1"></asp:CheckBox>
    <asp:Literal ID="litTC1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="litTC1Resource1" Text="I accept the"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="CnC" runat="server" Target="_blank" meta:resourcekey="CnCResource1">Condition of Carriage</asp:HyperLink>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvTermsConditions" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="checkAcceptance" ErrorMessage="Terms and Conditions must be accepted" meta:resourcekey="cvTermsConditionsResource1" Text="*"></asp:CustomValidator>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have put a breakpoint in the function and getting [image]

What is going wrong with this

Comment: Well, is there an element with that ID in the rendered HTML?

Comment: because .net renames the inputs. Plenty of dupes on this...

Comment: Following is the ID rendered  `<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" />I accept the
      <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CnC" href="/LionResources/en/Condition_of_Carriage.pdf" target="_blank">Condition of Carriage</a>
`

Comment: If you are using a masterpage, id will change. Check at runtime with developer tools of your browser the Id of the input. I recommend you use jquery and select the input by a own class.

Comment: I have a master page  ... @LeandroTupone

Comment: Yeah I know, thats why you have ctl00 in your id. I recommend you use JQuery, but let me answer a code without jq

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you all for the feedback 
The simplest solution i found when having a master page is to  read with clientid of the element

```js
function checkAcceptance(source, args) {
  args.IsValid = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>").checked;
}
```

This worked with no problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the element, because masterpage changes your Id.

I recommend you use JQuery, but if not, try with:

```
function checkAcceptance(source, args) {
       var idcheckbox = document.querySelector("[id*='CheckBox1']").id;
       args.IsValid = document.getElementById(idcheckbox).checked;
}
```

Or maybe you want to play with it, try with different selectors (CSS Method)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

**UPDATE:**
Using JQuery method:

Import JQuery script to your masterpage.
Use:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="CheckBox1Resource1" class="myclass"></asp:CheckBox>
```

and javascript:

```
args.IsValid = $(".myclass").prop("checked");
```

Comment: @makdu my fault, I type wrong the selector. Please try again with the fix.

Comment: @makdu np, let me know if it works, if not I'll glad to edit my answer, if it works please mark as accepted. :)

Comment: in any case I suggest you stop using masterpages. Its a headache and don't provides too much functionality or "speed rendition" improvement at runtime

Comment: I have found a simpler solution  `   function checkAcceptance(source, args) {

         args.IsValid = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBox1.ClientID %>").checked; 

     }`